# Time in conditional clause

Tags: time, conditionals

*I've gone through a lot of rules on conditional sentences in English and couldn't find the answer.*

What time should I use in the following comment to a source code?

1. `# Rebuild databases if 'exampleFile.sql' has changed`
2. `# Rebuild databases if 'exampleFile.sql' has been changed`
3. `# Rebuild databases if 'exampleFile.sql' was changed`
4. `# Rebuild databases if 'exampleFile.sql' is changed`
5. `# Rebuild databases if 'exampleFile.sql' changed`

The required meaning is "Perform a check. If, and only if, it is (?) detected that a certain file is (hmm?) changed due to some external forces, a script (that rebuilds a database) should be executed right after the check."

Answer (score 2):

Of those 5 I would go with #2

```
# Rebuild databases if 'exampleFile.sql' has been changed
```

due to the connotation of action having been actively taken to change it, rather than changes just happening to it. I would possibly consider saying instead

```
# Rebuild databases if changes have been detected in 'exampleFile.sql'
```

Comment: I find the _detected_ version pretty useful. However, I wonder if it shouldn't be _"...if changes **have been** detected in..."_?

Comment: Good point, I'll edit. Cheers jera.